# SharePoint 2013 Web Templates Masterpage not found

Tags: master-page, web-template

I created a new web template for SharePoint 2013 (as Farm solution, because it has to be selected when creating a new site collection).

The site collection creates succesfully. But when I navigate to the site I get an error that something went wrong. When I look in te ULS logs I get the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file /sites/za/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master does not exist.
```

Anybody any ideas?

Comment: It is actually the whole _catalogs folder that is not created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue. 
Because the property in my web template "ContainsDefaultLists" was set on TRUE and it should be FALSE

Comment: Your solution help me a lot. Thanks man. I had included ContainsDefaultLists="True" in my custom web template and it was throw the error you mentioned above. setting it to False or remove the ContainsDefaultLists completely solved the issue.